# What are the limits to changing my own unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, primarily-opinion-based

If a question has no answers and is closed, an edit will necessarily change some of my original intent. I am the OP, and it just wasn't working. How tightly do I have to stay in the box which didn't work?

Let's limit the discussion to "primarily opinion-based" closures. Making it "not opinion based" may require major changes. It may need to change some or all tags.

Comment: There is no limit probably other than being about the same work/characters.

Comment: TL;DR: whilst it’s technically fine, try and do it as little as possible. If you have a new question just ask a new one rather constantly asking a new question inside of an existing one.

Comment: Avoid making changes that invalidate the answers. Preferably, don't invalidate the comments although, if you do, tag the people who left those comments so they can decide whether to get rid of them.

Answer (score 15):

If your question is **unanswered and unvoted upon**, there are (theoretically) no limits whatsoever to changing ***any aspect of that question*** including, but not limited to, the tags, the property, the question itself or **any other part of it.**

If you're intending to utterly revise it, however, you would probably be better creating a new question and deleting the old one simply to make the edit history and any comment chain look less weird.

---

With that being said, you need to be aware that as soon as you post a question, people are probably starting to spend their time working on an answer to it. It's really quite anti-social to not take that into consideration, especially if people have been making comments to try to get a feel for what you're asking about and to formulate the best answer possible.

Comment: Slight disagreement - if you completely and utterly change the meaning, the votes on the question become irrelevant. Sure, folks can withdraw/change their votes after the edit, but... They won't necessarily notice, and somehow I think it's a problem to invalidate all these votes. (If it's at +0/-0 it's another matter)

Comment: @Jenayah - I've edited accordingly. Of course if it has votes on it (up or down), it should be deleted rather than comprehensively edited.

Comment: @Jenayah I think that would almost work against the person asking the question anyway.

Comment: @Alex oh, sure, it's technically possible, but I'd still abuse against it in general